# Spring Data Neo4j 3.3: PersistentEntityConversionException

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Hoping my team is doing something silly here, but, using SDN 3.3 against Neo4j 2.1.6, I'm getting a PersistentEntityConversionException when trying to fetch a particular entity.

The data model goes something like this:

- Have a base node entity model, call it A.  It's abstract in SDN (it actually descends from a couple other classes, but the root is @NodeEntity).
- Have two sibling entities, each of which descends from A.  Call these B and C.

I'm executing a Cypher query that effectively looks for nodes with the label from A (which should include B and C).  The Java code looks a bit like this:

```
List<A> nodeList = this.repo.getNodes();
```

I get the query back, and then iterate through the results and, using a template, "fetch" the results.  Eventually, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.PersistentEntityConversionException: Requested a entity of type 'class B', but the entity is of type 'class C'.
```

This method of fetching used to work in SDN 3.2.1.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging, I found the cause of my issues, and I'll admit I feel like a bit of a dope.

In reality, the models in the domain are a bit more complex (and a bit deeper) than what I'd posted.  For me, the issue boiled down to needing to set `enforceTargetType`to true and to also set the `elementClass`to the targeted type.

In other words, my A class had a relationship with yet another model (call it M), and that relationship wasn't properly annotated.

I ended up tracing through a good bit of the SDN code and found that it was only when I was trying to build that relationship with the associated M class that things were getting confused.

Still, Leward's answer above may help some others in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this and looks like a bug in Spring Data Neo4j.

I found a workaround to make it work: disable the type safety checking in Spring Data Neo4j.

In your Spring XML context, simply add:

```
<bean id="typeSafetyPolicy" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typesafety.TypeSafetyPolicy">
    <constructor-arg value="NONE" />
</bean>
```

Keep in mind that this can create undesired side effects. See the documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#entity_type_safety

Comment: Thanks for this.  Perhaps Michael Hunger or someone can comment on this?  I'll mark is as the answer if nothing else comes back.

Comment: Well, that fixed the issue but introduced another, namely checking via instanceof a particular abstract object.  Might be a side effect as you noted above.